# AWS CLI dynamodb update-item

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I need add a new entity in my table. I try this command, but not working

```
aws --region "us-east-2" dynamodb update-item --table-name TableName --key '{\"Id\":{\"S\":\"123123-1233-1233-1233-123123123\"}}' --update-expression "ADD Test :c" --expression-attribute-values '{\":c\": {\"M\": {\"Name\": {\"S\": \"Joe\"}}}}' --return-values ALL_NEW
```

Eror

```
An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the UpdateItem operation: Invalid UpdateExpression: Incorrect operand type for operator or function; operator: ADD, operand type: MAP, typeSet: ALLOWED_FOR_ADD_OPERAND
```

Comment: are you trying to use ADD to add to a MAP ? ADD is for numbers and lists.

Comment: I'm getting the same.

Here's my params object
```{"TableName":"zipcodes","Key":{"zipcode":{"S":"60601"}},"ExpressionAttributeValues":{":providerIds":{"SS":["2a29c770-90ba-11eb-b16b-81161550a6dc-1"]}},"UpdateExpression":"ADD providerIds :providerIds"}```